# JetBrains WebStorm - How to turn off auto HTML Element Insertion

Tags: webstorm, jetbrains-ide

So this has been a really frustration feature for me in WebStorm. When typing in HTML, if I type `a` followed by a <kbd>Space</kbd> it inserts `<a href=""></a>` it also does this for some other words as well (ex form). I want to turn this off. It is very frustrating when I'm just trying to type a message out to the user and it inserts a tag.

I have searched the forms and other places on the internet with no luck. I found a few sites that suggest turning off 'Insert closing tag on tag completion', and while that didn't sound like what I wanted I tried it anyway with no luck. What am I missing?? I've searched what feels like a hundred times in the preferences for a setting and can't find anything.

To date my work around is typing 'an' +  than arrowing over, backspacing the 'n' and then arrowing back over. While it works... it's not ideal to break my train of thought to remember to do that. Please Help.

Thanks all for the help

[image: WebStorm Smart Keys Setting for HTML]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must have `Space` specified as a key used to expand Emmet abbreviations. Check the **Settings | Editor | Emmet, Expand abbreviation with** and **Settings | Editor | Live Templates, By default expand with** options - changing these options to `Tab`, for example, should help